# selectText of NSTextField on focus

Tags: cocoa, select, focus, nstextfield

Could anybody suggest a method to select all the text of an `NSTextField` when the user clicks it?

I did find suggestions to subclass `NSTextField` and then use `mouseDown` or `firstResponder`,` but it's beyond my skill for now. So I was hoping either there would be an easier solution or somebody might be kind enough to detail the steps required.

Answer (score 24):

There isn't an easier solution, you need to subclass `NSTextField` to do what you want. You will need to learn how to handle subclassing if you are to do anything useful in Cocoa.

Text fields can be relatively complex to subclass because an `NSTextField` uses a separate `NSTextView` object called the Field Editor to handle the actual editing. This text view is returned by the `NSWindow` object for the `NSTextField` and it is re-used for all text fields on the page.

Like any `NSResponder` subclass, `NSTextField` responds to the methods `-acceptsFirstResponder` and `-becomeFirstResponder`. These are called when the window wants to give focus to a particular control or view. If you return `YES` from both these methods then your control/view will have first responder status, which means it's the active control. However, as mentioned, an NSTextField actually gives the field editor first responder status when clicked, so you need to do something like this in your `NSTextField` subclass:

```
@implementation MCTextField
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL result = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if(result)
        [self performSelector:@selector(selectText:) withObject:self afterDelay:0];
    return result;
}
@end
```

This first calls the superclass' implementation of `-becomeFirstResponder` which will do the hard work of managing the field editor. It then calls `-selectText:` which selects all the text in the field, but it does so after a delay of 0 seconds, which will delay until the next run through the event loop. This means that the selection will occur after the field editor has been fully configured.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked beautifully & made me learn a few things.

I created the .m file from the code you provided, the .h file like so :
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface MCTextField : NSTextField {}
@end

And in Interface Builder, I went to File -> Read Class File, selected the MCTextField.h, then I changed the class of my text field to be MCTextField.

Comment: This is ALSO the solution for a lot of general "select text programmatically" - the text-select routines in NSTextView, for instance, don't fire correctly if invoked directly on a lot of occasions, you need to put them in a performSelector:afterDelay:0 call. Sigh

Comment: This doesn't appear to work well in 10.9 SDK.  When I click the field, I get a  blinking caret unless I put a very long delay, like 1 second.

Comment: As @DanielWabyick noted, this solution no longer works.  I have just posted a new answer that does seem to work on OS X 10.10.  This stale answer should probably be removed.

Comment: I was very curious why all following ways doesn't work.
[self selectText:self];
[self performSelector:@selector(selectText:) withObject:self];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selectText:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
but only "[self performSelector:@selector(selectText:) withObject:self afterDelay:0];" work.
But you explained why! Thank you very much! I feel like found some treasure.!

Answer (score 6):

The answer from @Rob presumably worked at one point, but as @Daniel noted, it does not work any more.  It looks like Cocoa wants to track the mouse and drag out a selection in response to a click, and trying to select the text in response to `becomeFirstResponder` does not play well with that.

The mouse event needs to be intercepted, then, to prevent that tracking.  More or less by trial and error, I've found a solution which seems to work on OS X 10.10:

```
@interface MyAutoselectTextField : NSTextField
@end

@implementation MyAutoselectTextField
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [[self currentEditor] selectAll:nil];
}
@end
```

As far as I can tell, by the time `mouseDown:` gets called the field editor has already been set up, probably as a side effect of `becomeFirstResponder`.  Calling `selectAll:` then selects the contents of the field editor.  Calling `selectText:` on `self` instead does not work well, presumably because the field editor is set up.  Note that the override of `mouseDown:` here does *not* call `super`; `super` would run a tracking loop that would drag out a selection, and we don't want that behavior.  Note that this `mouseDown:` override doesn't affect selection once the textfield has become first responder, because at that point it is the field editor's `mouseDown:` that is getting called.

I have no idea what range of OS X versions this works across; if you care, you'll need to test it.  Unfortunately, working with `NSTextField` is always a little fragile because the way field editors work is so strange and so dependent upon the implementation details in `super`.

Answer (score 2):

Some updates with Swift:

```
import Cocoa

class TextFieldSubclass: NSTextField {
    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(theEvent)
        if let textEditor = currentEditor() {
            textEditor.selectAll(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Or for precise selection:

```
import Cocoa

class TextFieldSubclass: NSTextField {
    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(theEvent)
        if let textEditor = currentEditor() {
            textEditor.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(location, length)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Swift version, works for me:

```
import Cocoa

class TextFieldSubclass: NSTextField {
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let source = CGEventSourceCreate(CGEventSourceStateID.HIDSystemState)
        let tapLocation = CGEventTapLocation.CGHIDEventTap
        let cmdA = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, 0x00, true)
        CGEventSetFlags(cmdA, CGEventFlags.MaskCommand)
        CGEventPost(tapLocation, cmdA)
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Konstantin's solution, but that one will select on every mouse down. Here's a variation I'm using to select in `mouseDown` method, but only if it just became the first responder:

```
class SelectingTextField: NSTextField {

    var wantsSelectAll = false

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        wantsSelectAll = true

        return super.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)

        if wantsSelectAll {
            selectText(self)
            wantsSelectAll = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just use isHighlighted to check that

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here's an update for those who might stumble over this.

Override NSTextField and hook into becomeFirstResponder(). You won't have to worry about managing delegates or clicks. The tricky part is finding the field editor for the focused text field first before asking it to select all the text.

**Objective-C**

```c
// in AutoselectOnFocusTextField.h
@interface AutoselectOnFocusTextField : NSTextField
@end

// in AutoselectOnFocusTextField.m
@implementation AutoselectOnFocusTextField
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    if (![super becomeFirstResponder]) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSText* fieldEditor = [self currentEditor];
    if (fieldEditor != nil) {
        [fieldEditor performSelector:@selector(selectAll:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

**Swift**

```swift
class AutoselectOnFocusTextField: NSTextField {
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        guard super.becomeFirstResponder() else {
            return false
        }
        if let editor = self.currentEditor() {
            editor.perform(#selector(selectAll(_:)), with: self, afterDelay: 0)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```