# How to detect which NSTextField is clicked in Cocoa?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have two `NSTextField` objects which I want to highlight when user clicks on it.

The initial text field is already highlighted on `NSWindow` load. I am able to get mouse down event for text field click, but unable to distinguish which textfield did the user tapped.

I tried using hitTest on the text field using the `NSPoint` obtained from the `NSEvent` object, but the `NSView` returned is nil. The view it returns is that of the window's view and not that text field.

```
class SettingsViewController: NSViewController {
    private var sview: SettingsView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        initEvents()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        if let settingsView = SettingsView.createFromNib() {
            self.view = settingsView
            self.sview = settingsView as? SettingsView
        }
    }

    func initEvents() {
        self.sview!.emailTextField.delegate = self
    }

}

extension SettingsViewController: NSTextFieldDelegate, NSTextDelegate {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        self.log.debug("mouse down: \(event.buttonNumber), \(event.eventNumber), \(event.locationInWindow)")
        // How to know which text field triggered this?
    }

    func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
        self.log.debug("control delegate")
        return false
    }

    func textField(_ textField: NSTextField, textView: NSTextView, shouldSelectCandidateAt index: Int) -> Bool {
        self.log.debug("text field should select")
        return true
    }

    func textShouldBeginEditing(_ textObject: NSText) -> Bool {
        self.log.debug("text field should being editing")
        return true
    }
}

class SettingsView: NSView {
    private let log = Logger()
    private static var topLevelObjects: NSArray?
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: ASTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: NSSecureTextField!

    // ...
}
```

I am adding delegate to only one text field.

```
self.sview!.emailTextField.delegate = self
```

But when I click on the `passwordTextField`, I am getting the mouse click event as well. Why is this happening?

How to distinguish `NSTextField` mouse click and highlight the text field?

---

I tried subclassing `NSTextField` and adding click handler, but it is not working.

```
class ASTextField: NSTextField {
    private let log = Logger()

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        bootstrap()
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        bootstrap()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        bootstrap()
    }

    func bootstrap() {
        self.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ASTextField: NSTextFieldDelegate {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        // This is not working
        self.log.debug("mouse down")
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selectText of NSTextField on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195704/selecttext-of-nstextfield-on-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the `ASTextField` as below.

```
class ASTextField: NSTextField {

    // ...

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        self.sendAction(#selector(didClick(_:)), to: self)
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }

    @objc func didClick(_ event: NSEvent) {
        self.log.debug("did click")
    }
}
```

In the `SettingsView`, I missed calling `super.layout()`, without which the click won't work, nor the other text field will get focus when clicked.

```
class SettingsView: NSView {
    // ...

    override func layout() {
        self.log.debug("layout method")
        super.layout()  // This is important
    }
}
```

`NSTextField` delegate methods are not required.

Answer (score 3):

If what you're looking for is to be able to select the text when you click (focus) the text field, you can override the class to simplify your task and you won't have to worry about locating the clicked field from the delegate.

For an NSView object, when it gets focus (ie. clicking or tabbing) it will call `becomeFirstResponder` so we can hook in there.

When an NSTextField becomes editable (or selectable) it grabs a reusable 'field editor' and overlays it on top of your text field during the editing. If your NSTextField has focus, you can grab this field editor using the `currentEditor()` call on the view.

So, once you have the field editor, you can perform `selectAll` on the editor to select the text.

**Example class :-**

```swift
class AutoselectOnFocusTextField: NSTextField {
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        guard super.becomeFirstResponder() else {
            return false
        }
        if let editor = self.currentEditor() {
            editor.perform(#selector(selectAll(_:)), with: self, afterDelay: 0)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: @RohitVishwakarma I just tried copy-pasting this class AutoselectOnFocusTextField into a new Xcode 15 project, added an instance to a XIB and it worked as expected. What were you doing?

Answer (score 0):

The method you overwrote, `mouseDown(with)`, isn't a member of the `NSTextFieldDelegate` or `NSTextDelegate` protocols. You overwrote `NSViewController.mouseDown(with)`.

Whenever that method is called, the thing that was clicked is your `SettingsViewController`'s view.

To react to your textfield being selected, you use [`NSTextFieldDelegate .textField(_:textView:shouldSelectCandidateAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfielddelegate/2539557-textfield), which you already have. The value of the `textView` parameter is the text view that was selected.

Comment: Ah! That explains why the entire view responds to the click event. So how to detect text field click?

Comment: @jsloop I think you just came up with the best ever example as to why you shouldn't tack on delegate interfaces to view controllers, and make new standalone classes for them

Comment: The delegate is not getting invoked. I have created a sample project at https://github.com/jsloop42/purewind/tree/master/TestMacUI. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Why's that in objective C?

Comment: No specific reasons. I am working on a project that has both Objective-C and Swift and I like Objective-C more :) I have added a Swift target to the sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197778/discussion-between-alexander-and-jsloop).